# Can't make polaris colorpicker with textfield

Tags: reactjs, polaris

https://prnt.sc/0wK_hvH4BHsY
https://prnt.sc/82tPSS4uqZv8

**Is it possible to make this type of textfield + colorpicker with polaris react?**

I tried so many ways but couldn't make it.
when user clicks on black box it will show color picker.
And on change textfield value will be change also.
I analyze polaris documentation but didn't find any information to combine those two input.